# Is it possible to use a drag slider to slide between 4 images in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 images and a slider:

```
[image1.jpg]----[image2.jpg]----[image3.jpg]----[image4.jpg]
-----------------------------[Slider]-----------------------
```

Is it possible to click and drag the slider, so that when it is between position 1 and 2, images 1 and 2 are set to 50% transparency, then when the slider reaches position 2 image 2 is 100% opaque and image 1 is 100% transparent. Then when sliding from from position 2 to 3, image 2 becomes 90%, image 3 10%, next position image 2 80% image 3 20% etc... till the slider is at position 3 and image 3 is fully visable and image 2 is 100% transparent.

Is that possible? Would I use an array, or get the X position of the slider and adjust the images transparency accordingly?

Comment: This is definitely possible. Can you make a jsFiddle?  This calls for experimentation!

Comment: here is draggable image slider plugin; [royal slider](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my try: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/Pc3z4/). It uses jQuery but no plugins (and I believe it can be written using plain JavaScript as well).

The code is pretty self-explaining, but here's a commented version of the JavaScript part:

```
$(".slider").scroll(function() {
   var imgs = $(".slider img"); //find all images in the slider
    imgs.each(function() { //for each of them
        var cur = $(this); //save the current image in cur
        var lft = cur.offset().left; //find out its left offset
        if(lft <= 0) { //if it's been scrolled past (its offset is negative)
            cur.css({opacity: Math.max(0, (300 + lft) / 300)}); //then set its opacity to a value proportional to its left offset
        }
        else {
            cur.css({opacity: Math.min(1, (500 - lft) / 500)}); //it's not scrolled past yet; set its opacity appropriately
        }
    });
});
```

I hope that helped!

Comment: That is perfect thank you!!! I just need to arrange the images so they are on top of each other now. Thank you! :)

Comment: @GT22 If it worked for you don't forget to click the green tick next to this answer to mark it as accepted!

Comment: It did, but I can't get the images to sit on top of each other, so I'm not accepting it just yet. I'll keep playing with Z-index to see what I can come up with. Thanks for your help so far! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jQuery UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll), it has lots of features, including sliding though (divs with) images

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely 100% possible with a UI slider. I would take a look at jQuery's UI slider. Here is an example of how they use it to constantly change the color:

[Slider Demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#colorpicker)

While different, the general idea is the same -- as the value of the slider changes, you simply need to adjust that for the opacity of your images. I think the latter idea you had ("get the X position of the slider and adjust the images transparency accordingly?") is a really good way to tackle the problem. You could probably set it so that 0 is 100% visible for image1, 25 is 100% visible for image2, and so on. If you need more help braintstorming, let us know :]